# What should I do with a 3-way light switch that is no longer needed?

Tags: electrical, switch

How do I get rid of a 3-way switch?  I am rewiring some lights in an older home and found that one of the switches is a 3-way.  However, the light it was originally for was removed years ago.  So we have switches that are hot but we do not need.  The wires for the light were put into a base plug high up on the wall.  However, the switch in that room can remain to work the plug.  The one I am trying to remove is the other end of the 3-way in the kitchen.

Comment: What are the cables coming into each of the switches, what color wires in each, and where do they go (if you know)? There are a few different ways to wire 3-way switches, so the best answer depends on how yours is configured.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really remove the wire from the 3-way in the kitchen without tearing the wallboard out and removing it that way.  It's probably stapled above the boxes that it goes to or from.

You first need to determine if the receptacle is being fed from the 3-way.  If so then you might have to connect 2 of the wires that feed from the kitchen 3-way.  If the receptacle is being fed from someplace else then you still might have to connect the wires in the kitchen 3-way or open the receptacle up and remove the wires from the kitchen 3-way and then change the the other 3-way to a single pole.  The kitchen 3-way can have a blank cover put on it or you can buy a switch - blank plate or whatever configuration you need.  Make sure you turn the power off when working around the wires and when the power is on use a non-contact tester to determine what wires are hot.  When the power is on, keep one hand in your back pocket.